# nhibernate inheritance

Tags: nhibernate, inheritance, one-to-one

I have two tables:

- call_records
- crm_call_records

call_records do not know that crm_call_records and their corresponding classes exists in different assemblies. I can therefore not add a subclass mapping in the mapping file for call_records.

crm_call_records has a column named call_record_id which contains the value of the PK in call_records.

How should the mapping files look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter what assembly your classes are in.

If the subclasses are defined by records in a different table with the PK pointing to the parent class' id, then you have a [table per subclass](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#inheritance-tablepersubclass) strategy.